# How to compare array objects present in two different React states

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to compare object arrays present in two different React states. My state values are something like below:

```
review1 = [{name: John, Title: Manager},{name: Peter, Title: Engineer}, {name: Serena, Title: Supervisor}]
review2 = [{personName: John, ismanager: yes}, {name: Peter, ismanager: no}, {personName: Serena, ismanager: yes},{personName: John, ismanager:yes}]
```

Now I want to get count of people who are manager. If multiple then count should increase. In this case John is manager for two position then count for John is 2 and for Peter 0 and Serena 1

I am trying below function but it doesn't work as expected.

```
let filter = this.state.review1.map(elem=>elem.personName)
count = this.state.review2.map(data=> data.name).reduce((n,x) =>n +(x === filter.personName && data.ismanager === "yes"),null)

<div> John: {ismanger.count}, Serena: {ismanager.count}, Peter: {ismanager.count} </div>
```

Comment: do you want to count from `review1` the managers?

Comment: I want to count from review2

Comment: why not count then from `review2`?

Comment: Exactly I am counting it from ```review2``` but don't know how I can do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count directly the manager with the condition.

```js
var review2 = [{ personName: 'John', ismanager: 'yes' }, { personName: 'Peter', ismanager: 'no' }, { personName: 'Serena', ismanager: 'yes' }, { personName: 'John', ismanager: 'yes' }],
    count = Array.from(
        review2.reduce((m, { personName, ismanager }) => m.set(personName, (m.get(personName) || 0) + (ismanager === 'yes')), new Map),
        ([name, count]) => ({ name, count })
    );

console.log(count);
```

Comment: it works but if I do have multiple people having managers then it doesn't in my case. Something like below

Comment: ``` var review2 = [{ personName: 'John', ismanager: 'yes' }, { name: 'Peter',  ismanager: 'no' },  ``` ```{personName:'Serena', ismanager: 'yes'}] ```
    ```count = review2.reduce((s, { ismanager }) => s + (ismanager === 'yes'), 0);

console.log(count) ```

Comment: what is the wanted value then?

Comment: I want something like separate values for each of the person. Something like count of john is 1. Count of Serena is 1 and Count of Peter is 0

Comment: I have updated the post, so yes I have same manager value ismanager="yes" multiple times for few people

Comment: Result should be like `<div> John: {ismanger.count}, Serena: {ismanager.count}, Peter: {ismanager.count} </div> `

Comment: Updated answer is quite close but as John has ismanager: yes 2 times in the array object it should print count as 2 but it's printing 1

Answer (score 0):

I guess we only need to do it over `review2` array right?
Try this.

Demo At: [playcode](https://playcode.io/366205?tabs=script.js,preview,console)

```
review2 = [{personName: 'John', ismanager: 'yes'}, {name: 'Peter', ismanager: 'no'}, {personName: 'Serena', ismanager: 'yes'},{personName: 'John', ismanager:'yes'}]

const countMap = review2.reduce((accum, person) => {
  const isPersonName = !!person.personName;
  const name = isPersonName ? person.personName : person.name;
  if (accum[name] && person.ismanager === 'yes') {
    accum[name]++;
  } else if (person.ismanager === 'yes') {
    accum[name] = 1;
  }

  return accum;
}, {})

console.log(countMap);
```